# Need help in relation to the sort function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Hello I have a question related to the sort function in python.
So if I have 2 arrays x and y e.g

```
X = [1, 5, 6, 2]
Y = [2, 7, 5, 1]
```

If i sort x, y wont be effected but what if i want it to like follow that index if that makes sense like e.g

```
>>> X
[1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> Y
[2, 1, 7, 5]
```

Comment: You could merge them into a list of pairs e.g. `[(1,2), (5,7), (6,5), (2,1)]`. Then sort that list and then read off the second part of each pair.

Comment: to expand on Tom's suggestion: `[y for x, y in sorted(zip(X, Y))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the indices in `range(len(X))` based on the values of `X`, then update `X` and `Y` accordingly:

```
>>> X = [1, 5, 6, 2]
>>> Y = [2, 7, 5, 1]
>>> Z = sorted(range(len(X)), key=lambda i: X[i])
>>> X, Y = map(list, zip(*((X[i], Y[i]) for i in Z)))
>>> X
[1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> Y
[2, 1, 7, 5]
```